# Error when using std::vector::size to create another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning DSA and while practising my LeetCode questions I came across a question-( https://leetcode.com/problems/find-pivot-index/).
Whenever I use vector prefix(size), I am greeted with errors, but when I do not add the size, the program runs fine.
Below is the code with the size:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int pivotIndex(vector<int>& nums) {
        //prefix[] stores the prefix sum of nums[]
        vector<int> prefix(nums.size());
        int sum2=0;
        int l=nums.size();
        //Prefix sum of nums in prefix: 
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            sum2=sum2+nums[i];
            prefix.push_back(sum2);
        }
        //Total stores the total sum of the vector given 
        int total=prefix[l-1];
        for(int i=0; i<l;i++)
        {   
            if((prefix[i]-nums[i])==(total-prefix[i]))
            {
                return i;
            } 
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain this to me.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the constructor taking an integer as parameter does?

Comment: Please include the specific errors you see in the question

Comment: *"I am greeted with errors"* - these are not state secrets. You can share them. Honest. Put them [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73144100/edit) where they belong. **Always** include the exact verbatim errors in a question about errors.

Comment: Interesting the number of questions about programming coming from the Denver School of the Arts (DSA) lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use vector constructor with the integer parameter, you get vector with `nums.size()` elements initialized by default value. You should use indexing to set the elements:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < l; ++i){
    sum2 = sum2 + nums[i];
    prefix[i] = sum2;
}
...
```

If you want to use `push_back` method, you should create a zero size vector. Use the constructor without parameters. You can use `reserve` method to allocate memory before adding new elements to the vector.

Comment: They aren't uninitialized, they are default inserted (which in the case of `int` means they are all 0)

Answer (score 3):

You create `prefix` to be the same size as `nums` and then you `push_back` the same number of elments. `prefix` will therefore be twice the size of `nums` after the first loop. You never access the elements you've `push_back`ed in the second loop so the algorithm is broken.

I suggest that you simplify your algorithm. Keep a running sum for the left and the right side. Add to the left and remove from the right as you loop.

Example:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int pivotIndex(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
    int lsum = 0;
    int rsum = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);

    for(int idx = 0; idx < nums.size(); ++idx) {
        rsum -= nums[idx]; // remove from the right
        if(lsum == rsum) return idx;
        lsum += nums[idx]; // add to the left
        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ted! Yes, I have used the same algo in my final submission, the code in the post was just to clear off my doubts regarding vectors.